# Read in user input but have to distinguish from string/decimal/character in C

Tags: c, user-input

```
q - quit the program immediately. 
r <int> - //does something
i <int1> <int2> - //does something
d <int1> <ind2> - //does something
t <int1> <int2> - //does something
l - // does something
f <filename> - // does something
```

Basically a user would input

'q' and it would quit the function.

Or input 'r' '1' '3' and it should do something.

I've used sscanf before but that's only because I knew ints would come after the character choice.

For the last one

f   the user has to type in 'f' then the filename and it should open up the file.

How would I fit this part into the equation using sscanf. Currently my code looks like this.

```
printf("Please enter a choice ");
sscanf(sentence," %c %d %d", &choice, &val1, &val2)
```

but this wouldn't work if the user enters in 'f' "filenamehere.exe"

Comment: First get just the character that tells you how to proceed further. Then switch on that.

Comment: fgetc(), getch(), getche().  All these will read a single character.  Then you can jump to a deeper function to handle the expexted input.

Comment: My assignment requires that the input must be on one line.

Comment: Consider reading the whole line of input into a string (`fgets()`); then use `sscanf()` — or other simpler mechanisms — to read the first non-space char.  Depending on what you find, you can process the rest of the line.  This typically gives you better control over the error reporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is break your read up into two steps... first get the mode the user wants, then take action based on what the mode is...

```
char mode;

printf( "Please enter a choice " );
if( scanf( "%c", &mode ) < 1 )
{ 
    printf( "Could not read input\n" );
    exit( -1 );
}

switch( mode )
{
    case 'q': exit( 0 );
    case 'r':
    {
        int value;
        if( scanf( "%d\n", &value ) < 1 )
        {
            printf( "command 'r' requires you to input an integer value\n" );
            exit( -1 );
        }
        // do something with value
        break;
    }
    // etc...
}
```